# ion-content resizing when loading data dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework

i have an ion-nav-view inside ion-content.

i want to load data dynamically into ion-nav-view.

when loading data dynamically into ion-nav-view its not resizing to content height instead its loading in a small div with a scroll bar.

```
<ion-view view-title="My view">
   <ion-content class="padding">
    <div id="test">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
     </div>
     <ion-nav-view name="mydynview">
     </ion-nav-view>
   <ion-content >
</ion-view >
```

i am loading a template into "mydynview" from my controller.

### mytemplate.html:

```
 <ion-view view-title="About">

<ion-content class="padding" delegate-handle="testhandle">
<!-- <ion-nav-view> -->

    <p ng-click="onlc()">test</p>
    <p ng-click="onlc()">test</p>
    <p ng-click="onlc()">test</p>
    <p ng-click="onlc()">test</p>
    <p ng-click="onlc()">test</p>
<!-- </ion-nav-view> -->
</ion-content >
```

I read about resizing from here:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/

and even that is not working.

help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find something ?

Comment: not a perfect solution:
as $ionicScrollDelegate.resize() is not working, i have done it resizing on my own with js.

     var newHeight= $window.innerHeight;
  var tabsHeight =     document.getElementById('HIPACIonTabs').style.height;
  document.getElementById('MyHIPACIonNavView').style.height= (newHeight-230)+'px'; //taking window innerHeight and subtracting footer height, footer is 49px

Comment: Hi @praveenseela - I posted an answer below with a means of diagnosing if your problem is being caused by a timing issue because of async calls. `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize()` does work, you just have to make sure to call it after the content has loaded.

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/) states that you need to call `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize()` "after the content has loaded."

Since you did not post your controller, it's not possible for me to evaluate if your calling the `.resize()` method before the load is asynchronously completed.

Here's a quick and dirty way for you to test if it's a timing issue: call `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize()` within a `$timeout` with a 500ms delay. If that fixes the problem, you're calling `.resize()` before the content has finished loading so it doesn't have the complete view to calculate the new size accurately. This isn't a solution; it's a way to diagnose the problem. If it turns out this is the problem, then you want to call `.resize()` on your promise / callback / whatever that gets fired when your template is done loading.